# How to create an AWS S3 Bucket Policy Restricting Referer For MP3 Playback

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mp3, policy, referer

I am trying to link to mp3 recordings stored in S3 from my salesforce instance so that they open in a new tab and auto play.

When the bucket policy is set to public, the mp3 auto plays when you click on the link.

When the policy includes the referer condition, it successfully prevents the files from being accessed from other urls, but when the link is clicked from salesforce a black page loads with an audio file player which does not have the ability to play the mp3.

My current workaround, is to include the Content-Disposition = attachement key value pair so the mp3 downloads (works fine) but I would like to have the audio play in the browser.

Can anyone help?

```
This version restricts links to website.com and loads the page but can't play audio
{
    "Version": "2020-02-17",
    "Id": "BUCKET POLICY",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests from salesforce",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://website.com/*",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


This version does not restrict the referer and plays audio automatically when the link is clicked.

{
    "Version": "2020-02-17",
    "Id": "BUCKET POLICY",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests from salesforce",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```